# How (mathematical relation) and why (mechanism) do Time-to-Repetition (TR) and Time-to-Echo (TE) affect Signal-to-Noise-Ratio (SNR)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, thermodynamics, medical-physics, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

I want to understand why (what is the mechanism behind) lowering the time to echo (can we actually have T1-weighted Zero Time to Echo images) increases the Signal to Noise Ratio in (nuclear) Magnetic Resonance Imaging and why increasing the time to repetition decreases the Signal to Noise Ratio (can we have Zero Time to Repetition images and what happens then, 0 Signal to Noise Ratio) and how do they do so (what are the mathematical relations and what are the underlying assumptions to derive them).

I am studying medical physics and the textbook says nothing, my google-fu doesn't help either (no paper I read helps) and worst of all is that the professor doesn't answer my email nor do they hold office-hours (while they are supposed to).

**My question is How and why do Time to Repetition and Time to Echo affect Signal to Noise Ratio?**

I appreciate that everything happens to satisfy the principle of minimum energy but I can't understand how SNR and free energy are related or how free energy is reduced by an increase or decrease in SNR.